# " Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()"

Tags: mysql, php

[image: screenshot of error]

I'm using mysql Server version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu), trying to do a simple connection to the database but whenever I try to connect to the database, I get this error.

```
 127.0.0.1:34236 [500]: /process.php - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in
 /home/kipo/Desktop/php-crud/process.php:3 Stack trace:
 #0 {main}   thrown in /home/kipo/Desktop/php-crud/process.php on line 3
```

please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'd be needing to install the php-mysql package using apt.

> sudo apt-get install php-mysql

From there, restart apache2

> sudo service restart apache2

For a distro on systemd [If service is not a defined command], you can use:

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

Your script should be working after that